# R Shiny Reactive dplyr filters to form new dataframe to plot from

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, dplyr, reactive

I am trying to build a reactive plot that uses dplyr filter functions reactive to user inputs to pull the correct x,y coordinates to plot.

My UI:

```
choices <- c("Web" = 1,"Huddle" = 3, "Other" = 5, "Test" = 7)
role <- c("Student" = 1, "Not" = 2)
range <- c("2016"=2,"July 2017"=1)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Membership Satisfaction"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Value Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = 
icon("dashboard")),
  menuItem("Services Dashboard", tabName = "service", icon = 
icon("dashboard")),
  menuItem("Demographics Dashboard", tabName = "demos", icon = 
icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "demos",
          sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("inpt","Select variables to plot", choices = 
            choices),
            checkboxGroupInput("role", 
                               "Select Primary Role of Interest", 
                               choices = role),
            checkboxGroupInput("yrs", 
                               "Select year(S) of Interest", 
                               choices = range)),
          fluidPage(

            plotOutput("test")  

          )))))
```

and my server:

```
server <- function(input,output){


  x <- reactive({
    example1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(Product == as.integer(input$inpt))%>%
    dplyr::filter(year == as.integer(input$range)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(status == as.integer(input$role)) %>%
    pull(-2)
   })


  y <- reactive({
    example1 %>%
      dplyr::filter(Product == as.integer(input$inpt+1))%>%
      dplyr::filter(year == as.integer(input$range)) %>%
      dplyr::filter(status == as.integer(input$role)) %>%
      pull(-1)
  })

  z <- reactive({data.frame(x= x(), y = y())})


  output$test <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(z(), aes(x,y))+ 
    geom_point(colour ="green", shape = 17, size=5 )+ 
    labs(x = "Mean Satisfaction", y = "Mean Importance") + 
    xlim(0,5) + ylim(0,5)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=2.5) + geom_hline(yintercept =  2.5)})


       }



   shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Notes:

Example1 is a dataframe with summarized averages by group, year, and product.

X and Y variables filter to get a particular product code and stores just the mean values. Y is a corresponding and always product(x+1). It gets the average for y and stores those vales. Variable Z then creates a dataframe of x,y coordinate points to plot.

Example1 data head:

```
> example1
# A tibble: 24 x 5
# Groups:   year, status [12]
    year status Product AvgComImpt AvgComSat
    <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>     <dbl>
 1    1.     1. 1           NaN         2.70
 2    1.     1. 2             3.13    NaN   
 3    1.     2. 1           NaN         2.43
 4    1.     2. 2             3.33    NaN   
 5    1.     3. 1           NaN         2.40
 6    1.     3. 2             3.60    NaN   
 7    1.     5. 1           NaN         3.03
 8    1.     5. 2             3.30    NaN   
 9    1.     7. 1           NaN         3.50
10    1.     7. 2             4.00    NaN   


> dput(head(example1))
structure(list(year = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), status = c(1, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 3), Product = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), AvgComImpt = c(NaN, 3.12844036697248, 
NaN, 3.33333333333333, NaN, 3.6), AvgComSat = c(2.7037037037037, 
NaN, 2.42857142857143, NaN, 2.4, NaN)), .Names = c("year", "status", 
"Product", "AvgComImpt", "AvgComSat"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = 
c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("year", "status"), drop = TRUE, 
indices = list(
0:1, 2:3, 4:5), group_sizes = c(2L, 2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels 
= structure(list(
year = c(1, 1, 1), status = c(1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("year", "status"), drop = TRUE, .Names 
= c("year", 
"status")))
```

In theory it's supposed to work like this:

X would get this:

```
[1] 3.128440 3.333333 3.600000 3.296296 4.000000 4.000000 4.000000 4.234131 
4.254562 4.386861 4.090909 4.387218
```

Y would get this: 
    [1] 2.703704 2.428571 2.400000 3.034483 3.500000 2.666667 4.000000 3.856167 
    4.045455 3.825000 3.818182 3.996377

and then my Z would get this:

```
1  3.128440 2.703704
2  3.333333 2.428571
3  3.600000 2.400000
4  3.296296 3.034483
5  4.000000 3.500000
6  4.000000 2.666667
7  4.000000 4.000000
8  4.234131 3.856167
9  4.254562 4.045455
10 4.386861 3.825000
11 4.090909 3.818182
12 4.387218 3.996377
```

when i run it however, it says in the app:
    "Error: Results must have length 2, not 0."

When i make a selection on the variables to plot it changes to:
    "Error: Results must have length 1, not 0."

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with if there's no input selected and the error throws because the filter grabs the user input. But if that was the case, I'd think that making selections in all input areas would at least give a plot for that - but it doesn't. If this is what I'm doing wrong, I have no idea where to start... any help would be appreciated!

Any inputs/ideas on how I can get this code to work? THANKS!!!!

Comment: Try to use `reactive()` instead of `reactiveValues()`, and then refer to those as `x()` and `y()` instead of `x` and `y`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `z <- (x,y)` (which doesn't appear to be valid R syntax)? Maybe `z <- data.frame(x, y)`, or rather in a shiny server context, `z <- reactive({ data.frame(x = x(), y = y()) })`?

Comment: Sorry, that should've been z<- data.frame(x,y). I edited the code to change the reactiveValues() to reactive, and edited z  to be in line with @Aurèle.. I now get an error "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactiveExpr/reactive

Comment: Maybe try with `ggplot(z(), aes(x,y))` (note that I haven't run your code locally. To make it easier for us to help, you might replace your `head(example1)` output with a `dput(head(example1))` output, so that we could essentially copy-paste everything and run it locally to be able to reproduce your problem)

Comment: @Aurèle I put the dput(head(example1)) up. It's now giving me the error "no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "c('double','numeric')"

Comment: Thanks for editing your post. There's a typo (missing `%>%` before `pull(-2)`). If it doesn't solve it, I think the problem now lies in your data wrangling logic, not in Shiny per se

Comment: You also have a potential problem with comparing factors, characters, and integers in your Product column and your input$inpt. Try to make everything integer for instance, it'll make your life easier (you might have to convert inputs with as.integer(input$inpt) for instance

Comment: @Aurèle no luck! I edited my code.. now getting error  "Result must have length 1, not 0"  This code is killing me agh